# Size a JavaFX dialog with an embedded SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm creating a custom JavaFX dialog and I'd like to reuse an older class that extends `JPanel`. I embedded the panel in a `SwingNode` and set that as the dialogs content pane. It gets added ok, but the dialog does not get sized to show the whole panel. My understanding is that `JPanel`s don't do all of their sizing until they've been added to the UI, so when it is added to the `SwingNode` and then the `SwingNode` is added to the dialog, it's size is still 0,0. The panel's size gets updated a little while after the dialog is actually shown, but the dialog doesn't get resized.

Here is my minimum reproducible example:

```java
//Various imports here

public class SwingDialogInFxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        
        Button showDialogButton = new Button("Show FX/Swing dialog");
        showDialogButton.setOnAction(e -> new DialogWithSwingPanel().show());
        
        root.getChildren().add(showDialogButton);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private class DialogWithSwingPanel extends Dialog<Void> {
        public DialogWithSwingPanel() {
            SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JPanel swingPanel = new SomeSwingPanel();
                swingNode.setContent(swingPanel);
            });
            
            getDialogPane().setContent(swingNode);
        }
    }
    
    private class SomeSwingPanel extends JPanel {
        
        public SomeSwingPanel() {
            //Make this big just to illustrate my point
            this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the dialog appearing as tiny even thought the panel should be 1,000 by 1,000.

[image: Tiny dialog]

I did come up with a bit of a hack that almost works, but I'm still not really satisfied with it. I added a ComponentListener to the panel and then use it to resize the dialog. In other words, I changed the `DialogWithSwingPanel` constructor to:

```java
    private class DialogWithSwingPanel extends Dialog<Void> {
        public DialogWithSwingPanel() {
            
            SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JPanel swingPanel = new SomeSwingPanel();
                swingNode.setContent(swingPanel);
                
                swingPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                        DialogWithSwingPanel.this.setWidth(swingPanel.getWidth());
                        DialogWithSwingPanel.this.setHeight(swingPanel.getHeight());
                    }
                });
            });
            
            getDialogPane().setContent(swingNode);
            
        }
    }
```

By running the above code in my example, it would appear that it actually works, but when you try it with a panel that actually has content, you'll notice that some of it gets cut off. This is because I'm setting the dialog size to match the panel size, but it should actually be a little bigger to account for some margins and the title bar (I think). Setting the `SwingNode` size or setting the size on the value returned from `getDialogPane()` didn't do anything though, so for now the best I can do is the above solution and just adding a about 10 to the width and 20 to the height. It's not ideal.

Comment: You are executing `swingNode.setContent` in the AWT event dispatch thread;  that’s good.  However, `new SomeSwingPanel()` also needs run in the AWT event dispatch thread.

Comment: Good catch @VGR. I've updated my question. Unfortunately, that does not fix the sizing issue.